# Unable to change default rangeSelector Highstock

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to make 5M as my default rangeSelector but it seems that it keeps on insisting the 'all' on the selector.

```
   rangeSelector: {
            enabled: true,
            buttons: [{
                    count: 2,
                    type: 'minute',
                    text: '2M'
                }, {
                    count: 5,
                    type: 'minute',
                    text: '5M'
                }, {
                    count: 15,
                    type: 'minute',
                    text: '15M'
                }, {
                    count: 30,
                    type: 'minute',
                    text: '30M'
                }, {
                    count: 3,
                    type: 'hour',
                    text: '3H'
                }, {
                    count: 1,
                    type: 'day',
                    text: '1D'
                }, {
                    count: 30,
                    type: 'day',
                    text: '30D'
                }, {
                    type: 'all',
                    text: 'All'
                }],
            selected: 5,
        },
```

Can someone tell me where my code goes wrong ?
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed my problem by adding **allButtonsEnabled: true** and changing selected: **1**. I just got a bit confused a while ago

```
   rangeSelector: {
            enabled: true,
            allButtonsEnabled: true,
            buttons: [{
                    count: 2,
                    type: 'minute',
                    text: '2M'
                }, {
                    count: 5,
                    type: 'minute',
                    text: '5M'
                }, {
                    count: 15,
                    type: 'minute',
                    text: '15M'
                }, {
                    count: 30,
                    type: 'minute',
                    text: '30M'
                }, {
                    count: 3,
                    type: 'hour',
                    text: '3H'
                }, {
                    count: 1,
                    type: 'day',
                    text: '1D'
                }, {
                    count: 30,
                    type: 'day',
                    text: '30D'
                }, {
                    type: 'all',
                    text: 'All'
                }],
            selected: 1,
        },
```

Comment: that will make the buttons enabled by default. Did you check if the zooming is working on them. Can yo please provide the updated jsfiddle?